In plesk how to make the larvel app create a database
In plesk how to make the larvel app create a database , i have try this put did not work on the server
DB::statement("CREATE DATABASE $databaseName");

DB::statement("CREATE USER '$dbUser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$dbPassword'");
DB::statement("GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $databaseName.* TO '$dbUser'@'localhost'");


You have to create the database in your Plesk control panel. Laravel will, or better should not have the rights to create a database using its db user. After creating the database, you can add the credentials to the .env file and create migrations to create the tables in the new database
